# how to add a triangle to UILabel to make it look like a tooltip?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, core-graphics

I want to make a tooltip like UILabel with some custom code. I managed to add a triangle to the UILabel, but since it's out of the bound (or frame) of the UILabel itself. It's not drawing on the screen.

Here's my approach:

```
- (void) addTriangleTipToLayer: (CALayer *) targetLayer{
[targetLayer setBackgroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(0, targetLayer.frame.size.height);
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(15, targetLayer.frame.size.height);
UIBezierPath *trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

CGFloat middleX = (startPoint.x + endPoint.x) / 2;
CGFloat middleY = 7.5 * tan(M_PI / 3);

CGPoint middlePoint = CGPointMake(middleX, -middleY);

[trianglePath moveToPoint:startPoint];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:middlePoint];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:endPoint];
[trianglePath closePath];
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180);
[trianglePath applyTransform:rotate];

CAShapeLayer *triangleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[triangleLayer setFillColor: [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[triangleLayer setPath:trianglePath.CGPath];
[targetLayer addSublayer:triangleLayer];
```

}

I also convert the label into a image content for the use as a Google Map Marker Icon. here's the other things I did to this UILabel.

```
UILabel *klabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20)];
[klabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:9]];
[klabel setText: @"Tower"];
// here I apply the add triangle function to the uilabel.layer
[self addTriangleTipToLayer:klabel.layer];
//set the label to fit text content before rendered as a image
[klabel sizeToFit];
//convert the uilabel to image content
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(klabel.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[klabel.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * kicon = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// the rest of code is just use the image content as marker icon on google map.
kaliaMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
kaliaMarker.tappable = NO;
kaliaMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.283652, -157.836971);
kaliaMarker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
kaliaMarker.icon = kicon;
kaliaMarker.map = self.mapView;
```

the `targetLayer` is the `myLabel.layer`, which is where I add my triangle to. the problem is the `middleY` is `-12.4` from the calculation, and I guess it fell out of the visible bound/frame of my UILabel and you just can't see it.

I'm wondering what should I do or what is the proper approach to increase the visible part of my UILabel to show this little triangle.

Thanks for you guys' help!.

P.S. it should look like this.

[image]

But it looks like this. if I rotate the path by 90 degree, I can see the half triangle, it's there of course. So for 180 degree, the entire triangle is out of bounds which can not be seen..
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This slightly modified code works fine. I changed the argument of the method to UIView so that I could access its background color to make the triangle that same color, and made the y value of the triangle's point proportional to the height of the view.

```
- (void) addTriangleTipToLayer: (UIView *) view{
    CALayer *targetLayer = view.layer;
    [targetLayer setBackgroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(0, targetLayer.frame.size.height);
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(15, targetLayer.frame.size.height);
    UIBezierPath *trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    CGFloat middleX = (startPoint.x + endPoint.x) / 2;
    CGFloat middleY = targetLayer.frame.size.height * 1.8;

    CGPoint middlePoint = CGPointMake(middleX, middleY);

    [trianglePath moveToPoint:startPoint];
    [trianglePath addLineToPoint:middlePoint];
    [trianglePath addLineToPoint:endPoint];
    [trianglePath closePath];

    CAShapeLayer *triangleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [triangleLayer setFillColor: view.backgroundColor.CGColor];
    [triangleLayer setPath:trianglePath.CGPath];
    [targetLayer addSublayer:triangleLayer];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually your arrow is there, your background is white color so, you can't see that. Set a fill color to your layer.

```
[triangleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
```

Comment: I tried it, it's not working which is very frustrating. Does it matter when to call `setClipsToBounds` ?.

Comment: clipsToBounds is NO by default, so this isn't likely to work.

Comment: @IanZhao: I tried your code and it's working for me, the only thing I saw was it is added on top left of your label. Not at the bottom left

Comment: @rdelmar: Yes, you are correct. I found the actual reason and updated my answer

Comment: @MidhunMP too bad, it's still disappeared, I've updated my question to show the rest of things I did to this UILabel, see if it helps, but thank you guys for confirming the existence of my arrow.

Answer (score 1):

I found problem in my code.

```
//convert the uilabel to image content
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(klabel.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
```

did not include enough space for the arrow layer added to the uilabel.
Also I add the triangle in the wrong way. The correct code should be:

```
[targetLayer setBackgroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

CGFloat side = targetLayer.frame.size.height;

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(targetLayer.frame.size.width / 2 - side / 2, side);
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(targetLayer.frame.size.width / 2 + side / 2, side);
UIBezierPath *trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

CGFloat middleX = targetLayer.frame.size.width / 2;
CGFloat middleY = (side / 2) * tan(M_PI / 3) + side;
CGPoint middlePoint = CGPointMake(middleX, middleY);

[trianglePath moveToPoint:startPoint];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:middlePoint];
[trianglePath addLineToPoint:endPoint];
[trianglePath closePath];

CAShapeLayer *triangleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[triangleLayer setFillColor: [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[triangleLayer setPath:trianglePath.CGPath];
[targetLayer addSublayer:triangleLayer];
```

this will add equilateral triangle center to the label itself. then the code to draw the convert to images should be:

```
    //convert the uilabel to image content
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGRectMake(self.klabel.bounds.size.width, 2 * self.klabel.bounds.size.height), NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
```

[image: end result will look like this] thanks for you guys' help!